# Java - check if java file is well written

Tags: java, parsing, compilation, compiler-errors

My java application has to parse a lot of java source codes, I am using this parser https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser.

This is the function in which I call another function that parses a single file:

```
private static void createSimplifiedAST(String userFolder, String userProjectFolder, ArrayList userProjectFiles){
    File projectDir = new File(usersFolderPath + userFolder + "/" + userProjectFolder);

    // explore all java files inside a directory (user's project folder)
    new DirExplorer((level, path, file) -> path.endsWith(".java"), (level, path, file) -> {
        System.out.println(path);
        System.out.println(Strings.repeat("=", path.length()));

        // create root of simplified AST of user's single file
        TreeNode<String> projectSingleFile = new ArrayMultiTreeNode<String>("projectFileTreeRoot");

        // create simplified AST of user's single file
        declarationNumber = 0;
        forNumber = 0;
        forEachNumber = 0;
        whileNumber = 0;
        try {
            iterateASTNodes(file, projectSingleFile);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaSourceCodeParser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaSourceCodeParser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        // prints single file tree
        System.out.println(projectSingleFile);

        // save simplified ASTs to txts
        saveASTToTxt(userFolder, userProjectFolder, file, projectSingleFile);

        // add simplified AST of single file to user's project files array list
        userProjectFiles.add(projectSingleFile);

    }).explore(projectDir);
}
```

And this is the function to parse a single file:

```
private static void iterateASTNodes(File file, TreeNode<String> treeNode) throws ParseException, IOException{
    try {
        new NodeIterator(new NodeIterator.NodeHandler() {
            @Override
            public boolean handle(Node node) {
                if (node instanceof VariableDeclarator) {
                    treeNode.add(new ArrayMultiTreeNode<>("declaration" + declarationNumber));
                    declarationNumber++;
                    return false;
                } else if (node instanceof ForStmt) {
                    treeNode.add(new ArrayMultiTreeNode<>("for" + forNumber));
                    forNumber++;
                    iterateASTNodesWrapper(node, treeNode.find("for" + (forNumber - 1)));
                    return false;
                } else if (node instanceof ForeachStmt) {
                    treeNode.add(new ArrayMultiTreeNode<>("foreach" + forEachNumber));
                    forEachNumber++;
                    iterateASTNodesWrapper(node, treeNode.find("foreach" + (forEachNumber - 1)));
                    return false;
                } else if (node instanceof WhileStmt) {
                    treeNode.add(new ArrayMultiTreeNode<>("while" + whileNumber));
                    whileNumber++;
                    iterateASTNodesWrapper(node, treeNode.find("while" + (whileNumber - 1)));
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }).explore(JavaParser.parse(file));
    } catch (ParseException | IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("  ERROR: lexical error!");
    }
}
```

This is the NodeIterator class:

```
public class NodeIterator {
    public interface NodeHandler {
        boolean handle(Node node);
    }

    private NodeHandler nodeHandler;

    public NodeIterator(NodeHandler nodeHandler) {
        this.nodeHandler = nodeHandler;
    }

    public void explore(Node node) {
        if (nodeHandler.handle(node)) {
            for (Node child : node.getChildrenNodes()) {
                explore(child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the DirExplorer class:

```
public class DirExplorer {
    public interface FileHandler {
        void handle(int level, String path, File file);
    }

    public interface Filter {
        boolean interested(int level, String path, File file);
    }

    private FileHandler fileHandler;
    private Filter filter;

    public DirExplorer(Filter filter, FileHandler fileHandler) {
        this.filter = filter;
        this.fileHandler = fileHandler;
    }

    public void explore(File root) {
        explore(0, "", root);
    }

    private void explore(int level, String path, File file) {
        try {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                for (File child : file.listFiles()) {
                    explore(level + 1, path + "/" + child.getName(), child);
                }
            } else {
                if (filter.interested(level, path, file)) {
                    fileHandler.handle(level, path, file);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("  ERROR: something went wrong!\n");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program, at some point, it stops while parsing this file:

```
public class Test {
    /**<caret>
    public void foo() {
    }
}
```

I have understood that it stops because of a lexical error, this:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.github.javaparser.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 6, column 2.  Encountered: <EOF> after : ""
at com.github.javaparser.ASTParserTokenManager.getNextToken(ASTParserTokenManager.java:2480)
at com.github.javaparser.ASTParser.jj_ntk(ASTParser.java:9154)
at com.github.javaparser.ASTParser.ClassOrInterfaceBody(ASTParser.java:829)
at com.github.javaparser.ASTParser.ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration(ASTParser.java:470)
at com.github.javaparser.ASTParser.TypeDeclaration(ASTParser.java:398)
at com.github.javaparser.ASTParser.CompilationUnit(ASTParser.java:203)
at com.github.javaparser.JavaParser.parse(JavaParser.java:111)
at com.github.javaparser.JavaParser.parse(JavaParser.java:158)
at com.github.javaparser.JavaParser.parse(JavaParser.java:177)
at javasourcecodeparser.JavaSourceCodeParser.iterateASTNodes(JavaSourceCodeParser.java:89)
at javasourcecodeparser.JavaSourceCodeParser.lambda$createSimplifiedAST$1(JavaSourceCodeParser.java:178)
at javasourcecodeparser.DirExplorer.explore(DirExplorer.java:35)
at javasourcecodeparser.DirExplorer.explore(DirExplorer.java:31)
at javasourcecodeparser.DirExplorer.explore(DirExplorer.java:31)
at javasourcecodeparser.DirExplorer.explore(DirExplorer.java:31)
at javasourcecodeparser.DirExplorer.explore(DirExplorer.java:31)
at javasourcecodeparser.DirExplorer.explore(DirExplorer.java:31)
at javasourcecodeparser.DirExplorer.explore(DirExplorer.java:31)
at javasourcecodeparser.DirExplorer.explore(DirExplorer.java:31)
at javasourcecodeparser.DirExplorer.explore(DirExplorer.java:24)
at javasourcecodeparser.JavaSourceCodeParser.createSimplifiedAST(JavaSourceCodeParser.java:194)
at javasourcecodeparser.JavaSourceCodeParser.main(JavaSourceCodeParser.java:225)
```

Now, this error stops the entire program and I am not able to parse the other "good" codes.

What I want is that the program has to skip the file with lexical errors and continuing to parse the other files.

Any ideas? Maybe trying to compile each file and parsing it only if the compilation succeeds?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, ***tool, software library***, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not shown us the stacktrace, but I expect that the exception is thrown in this method call:

```
JavaParser.parse(file)
```

If so, the solution is simply to restructure your code so that you can catch exceptions thrown by that call, and then proceed to the next file.

Comment: Yes, and I have already tried with try-catch statements, but the error stops the program anyway, but I don't know if I am using it correctly, so could you give me an example of try catch for my code?

Comment: How about you show us the code that you tried.  The actual code.  Also, the actual stacktrace.

Comment: Are you sure that you are catching the correct exceptions in `iterateASTNodes`?    The stacktrace says it is `TokenMgrError` ...

Comment: Oh right, I am running the program right now and it doesn't seem to stop, thank you.

Comment: I also added a catch for Error in iterateASTNodes because of some escape errors